# TCP - single connection, how to not block main application

Tags: python, sockets, tcp

I open a single TCP connection to a gateway PC. My application will send messages to the gateway which will process the payload and pass on the message to another computer (based on payload) for processing.

For example, I send message A over the TCP connection which will be routed to computer A for response. But I may also need to send message B which goes to computer B.

Currently I simply use `send(messageA)` and then use `recv()` to wait for the response. The downside is that the `recv()` will block which means I can't send message B until something is received (and I can't do any other tasks).

I have read about the following options but am confused to the best for my use case.

- **Make the socket non-blocking**. I send message A, call `recv()` (let's assume there is some delay in processing such that nothing is received immediately; so code moves on), move on to send message B and again call `recv()`. Now, it could be A or B that responds, which I can handle. But I need to call `recv()` again since only one response received so far; but what if computer A is down and never responds -- at some point I need to decide to stop calling recv(), right? On what basis would I do this?
- **Set a timeout on the socket**. Again, send message A but assume computer A is down, so the code will wait for timeout before moving on which is wasted time.
- **Use `select`**. Since I have only one socket and I don't think that helps here; plus, I understand `select` will block unless a timeout is set so no different, in this case, to the option above?
- **Use multithreading**. Have one thread to process the main application and do the sending. And another thread that just calls `recv()` in an infinite loop (or a long timeout) that calls a callback whenever data is available. But then if the connection is closed from the main thread, will the recv thread cause an exception or hang?

I am really not sure what best practices are or the pitfalls of the options above. Which would be best option or is there another option?

(I'm using Python, in case it makes a difference).

Comment: You are connected to the gateway PC, not to computer A/B directly.  So if they go down, you have no way of knowing, unless the gateway PC tells you explicitly, or you timeout the response reading, as you already mentioned.

Comment: In the multithreading scenario ,you can mix multiple approaches. For example, using `select()` with a blocking socket, so that you don't try to `recv()` until there is actually something to read, and you can also wait on another signal at the same time for when you are ready to end the thread. And FYI, `send()` can also block, so I would suggest moving that out of the main thread, too.

Comment: There really is not "one" best practice. The non-blocking+``select`` option is basically ``async`` and the tons of frameworks. The ``threading`` option is basically webservers and the tons of frameworks. Even manual handling with timeouts are probably used by lots of special-purpose applications. You would have to precisely define what you need and what tradeoffs you are willing to make (concurrency? latency? best/worst case? ...).

Comment: Thanks. My current thought, based on the comments above, is to have ```select``` running in one thread and a separate (let's call it ```main```) thread which decides what to send and what to do with received data; with buffers used to share the read/write data between threads.

I will look into async to see if that could work.